# Weblogic 11g Create new User exception

Tags: oracle, authentication, jakarta-ee, weblogic, soa

I'm trying to create new user in WebLogic 11g security realm.

```
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(env);
wls = (MBeanServer) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jmx/runtime");
//userEditor is SqlAuthenticator provider.
wls.invoke(userEditor, "addMemberToGroup", new Object[] { groupName, username}, new String[] {"java.lang.String", "java.lang.String"});
```

while doing it I'm getting the following exception:

```
javax.management.MBeanException: MBean invoke failed: weblogic.management.utils.InvalidParameterException: 1. [Security:099069]The password length can not be less than 8.
2. [Security:099113]The number of numeric or special characters in a password can not be less than 1.
```

My problem is that I can't find any option in webLogic 11G console to set password complexity for SqlAuthenticator provider. Is there any way to change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually set at the Password Validation provider level now, rather than at the specific authentication provider level, which makes sense - you're mandating a minimum level of complexity across the board.

You can see where the configuration is here:

http://www.screencast.com/users/kevinpowe/folders/Jing/media/3543eb50-d7c1-4070-8273-c122ae1adecd

If you click the link on the main page there, that takes you straight to the page where you can configure the options regarding complexity - numbers, lowercase chars, uppercase chars, etc.